# Session support in Now.js

Tags: node.js, express, connect, nowjs-sockets

Now.js quotes:

> Simply pass a connect or express http server in nowjs.initialize and this.user.session should be available.

So:

```
express = require 'express'
app = module.exports = express.createServer()
connect = require 'connect'
nowjs = require 'now'
everyone = nowjs.initialize(app)
```

The output of this.user is:

```
{ 
  clientId: '353725111301231610',
  cookie: { 'connect.sid': 's0meC00k1e1nF0rm4ti0n' },
  session: undefined 
}
```

Any idea why session is undefined?

Comment: You forgot to use the session middleware :)

Comment: I found the now.js session support by ianserli with the middleware, but I'm talking about the native session support from Now.js 0.8.0. Still don't know how to get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem and turns out it was happening because I was initializing NowJS before configuring express.

```
app.configure(function(){
    ...

    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: "my_key", store: redisStore }));
    app.use(app.router);
});

var everyone = nowjs.initialize(app); //must be defined after app.configure
```

One thing to note is that session is not set until a request is made to the server so if the server is reset, the client socket will reconnect but session will be undefined until the browser does a page refresh.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. Anybody have a working example I can look at? Forced to use the sessionStore.get method instead. Does using a MemoryStore not work?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution (CoffeeScript), for every "everyone"-request:

```
self = this
sid = decodeURIComponent(this.user.cookie['connect.sid'])
sessionStore.get sid, (err, session) ->
    self.user.session = session
    <<more code here>>
```

Any way to get to this.user.session directly?