# Should I be using socket.io for my nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nowjs-sockets

I am learning HTML5 and doing so by building a simple chatroom using Express, PassportJS, Mongoose/MongoDB, connect-mongoose, NowJS.

Everything works perfectly, except for one big problem: I am having trouble authenticating NowJS.

The usual way of doing this is to read the "this.user.cookie" property server-side and parse the string. However, for some reason, cookies is not being sent back to the server. (details here: [NowJS cookie field in this.user is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555626/nowjs-cookie-field-in-this-user-is-empty)) After a lot of googling, I think there are no alternative, secured, way for me to authenticate NowJS connections/clients.

**Question**

I am thinking of stripping all of NowJS out of my web app, and using socket.io directly. Is socket.io easy with work with? Would I lose key functionality if I switch to socket.io, instead of using NowJS?

Can I use socket.io to:

1) Call server-side functions?

2) Share server-side variables with the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io does not share variables or allow you to call server side functions. It allows you to bind and emit events on the client side and server side.

As for your cookie not being sent, its most likely that its being considered a cors, cross domain request, this can happen if your using a different port for socket.io then the http server that set the cookie.

Comment: Interesting. I am using www.mywebsite.com:3000 instead of www.mywebsite.com because Dreamhost does not allow us to bind to port 80. So that could be the problem! Is there anyway to resolve this? I suppose I will run into the same problem when trying to authenticate socket.io connections using cookies? Perhaps I should be switching host instead!

Comment: Do you have socket.io listening on port 3000 as well? https://github.com/alphapeter/socket.io-express is a good library to show how to authenticate socket.io with express v3, I altered a little bit for my needs but it worked well.

Comment: Yes it is listening on port 3000 as well. Dreamhost has Apache listening on port 80 and we are not allowed to unbind it. I will run into problems with socket.io too because of that right?

Comment: YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER! I switched to port 8080 and the cookie got passed to NowJS correctly!!! Thanks!

Comment: No problem Legendre, glad I could help!

Comment: Interesting...the cookie stopped coming over after a while, even though I am still listening to 8080. Weird. Well, at least I know the exact problem.

Comment: It worked again when I set up a proxy forwarding 80 to 8080, then listened to 8080. i.e. Put Apache in front of Node, which is dumb and defeats the whole point of Node yes. But I suppose that will have to do until I switch hosts. :p